# echoing out a button with an onclick window redirect that has a variable in it

Tags: php, html

What i'm doing is for ever file found I'm echoing out a table row that contains the name of the file, the size and a button to delete it. There delete button sends the file name via GET to a php file but I'm struggling to get the file name variable in the echo. Please help.

Code:

```
foreach(glob("*.*") as $files){
    echo '<tr><td>'
     . $files
     . "</td><td>"
     . filesize($files)
     . "Kb"
     . "</td><td>"
     . '<input type="button"  value="Delete" 
               onClick=\"window.location=\http://scripting.maxtstuff.com/logintest/delete.php/?df=true&ftdn=$files />"'
     . "</td></tr>";
}
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is a button that redirects to http://scripting.maxtstuff.com/logintest/delete.php/?df=true&ftdn=test.html
then my php file will delete it.

Comment: There is something wrong with your quotes inside that input tags onClick handler. Check (and post!) the generated html markup to see the problem.

Comment: You forgot the third layer of quotes!

Comment: try print_r($_GET) and post us the result....

Answer (score 0):

Try `onclick="window.location.href=\'http://scripting.maxtstuff.com/logintest/delete.php/?df=true&ftdn='.$files.'\';"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: `'....df=true&ftdn=$files />"'`. PHP doesn't parse strings that are delimited by single quotes, that's all. You can get around this by *either* concatenating using the `.` operator:

```
'...df=true&ftdn='.$files.'" />';
```

Or by delimiting your string using double quotes:

```
"...df=true&ftdn=$files\" />";
```

Note that, in the last case, you'll have to escape all double quotes inside the string, or replace them with single quotes (HTML accepts those, too).

Comment: This worked, Thanks a bunch for helping me out there. I understand it too, quite simple.

Comment: @RobertBowlingJr.: Happy to help... would you mind awfully accepting my answer, if it solved your problem? - I know, I'm a rep-whore ;)